# Iotstartup Application data not ready on IoT Enterprise

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-10-iot-core, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I have a UWP background app that previously ran on Windows IoT Core that I now need to run on Windows IoT Enterprise (Windows 10 Enterprise) and have been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/embeddedmode) tutorial to try and debug it on the remote machine.

Unfortunately whenever I run 
**iotstartup list**
to try and set my program as a startup task I get the error **Application data is not ready: 0x80004002**

When debugging directly onto the machine, the code doesn't hit the initial breakpoint as background tasks only automatically start on IoT Core.

Comment: Where is your "initial breakpoint"?

Comment: public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
The initial entrypoint. That's less of an issue as another 1 line test app that gets past the entry point still won't show up - the **iotstartup list** just won't play ball

Comment: In order to run background application on IoT Enterprise, you need [enable embedded mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/embeddedmode).